# Helicone Integration with openAI

Tags: javascript, node.js, openai-api

I am integrating helicone with the openAI(with gpt-4 model) in nodejs, getting unauthorized error(401), even after providing the proper helicone api key and gpt api key , followed the documentation of the helicone but those functions of openAI are not working with nodejs

`let response = await openai.createChatCompletion({ model: "gpt-4", messages: [{ role: "user", content: prompt }], });`

Tried with the above code

let response = await openai.createChatCompletion({
model: "gpt-4",
messages: [{ role: "user", content: prompt }],
});